# My app in background is using 70Mb, how to release memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a game that while running is going at 60fps and is more or less eficient in every way, but the problem is when I enter background. Im doing pause in two ways, this first method runs when you touch the in-game pause button:

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        for (UITouch *touch in touches)
        {
            CGPoint location3 = [touch locationInNode:self.pauseLayer];
            SKSpriteNode *touchedNode3 = (SKSpriteNode *)[self.pauseLayer nodeAtPoint:location3];

            if (touchedNode3.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == pausa)
            {
                    if (_gameIsPaused == NO) 
{
                    [self.world setPaused:YES];
                    [self.backWorld setPaused:YES];
                    [self setPaused:YES];
                    _gameIsPaused = YES;
                    [self.pauseLayer setPaused:NO];
                    [self showPauseMenu];
                }
else
                {
                    [self.world setPaused:NO];
                    [self.backWorld setPaused:NO];
                    [self setPaused:NO];
                    _gameIsPaused = NO;
                    [self hidePauseMenu];
                    [self.pauseLayer setPaused:YES];

                }
```

And when you enter background I have this in my app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
SKView* view = [self getSKViewSubview];

    if (view) {
        view.paused = YES;
    }
```

}

The problem is while running in background my app is still consuming memory, and sometimes when I open another app, my game crash. In this image you can see the consumption of my app while running background:
[image]

My question is if there is a way to prevent that crash, shall I release memory manually doing tasks before leaving the game??
I've tried entering background both ways, with the pause menu enabled and with the pause menu disabled. Sometimes it crash and it looks like is random. Therefore the memory consumption is always the same. Would be the best practice to release everything except the important things like points, position of the player, time, current world were you are, etc, etc, etc and destroy everything else? In this case, how could I do that? to destroy everything and to keep score, points, etc?

Comment: Your best bet is to reproduce and analyze the crash that occurs when your app is in the background respectively recovering from it. You should not need to worry about your apps background memory usage though, iOS takes care of that. I believe it may even take a memory snapshot and store it on disk for later resume rather than keeping contents in "real" memory. Also if you find background mode is a problem you could simply turn off background mode for your app.

Answer (score 1):

iOS kills backgrounded apps when it needs more memory, without any warning to the app. It's up to the app to save it's state when it enters the background in case the system kills it, and then restore state again when launched.

If you're still debugging in Xcode when the system decides to kill your app, it'll show up as a SIGKILL if I remember correctly, but it's not a crash, iOS is just terminating your app without warning.

The only way to lower memory usage in the background is to unload images, etc. when the app enters the background, but for a game that could cause annoying loading/freezing when the user switches apps... Normally all apps need to do is free any unnecessary or reloadable resources (cached images, etc) when a low memory warning is received...

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing I get to the SIGKILL, it happens when I open another game, a 3D one like walking dead. Only happens with big apps, not with whats'app or safari, and it doesn't restore any state.

[image]

I get this trying to reproduce the crash to upload an image.